# How to deserialize the body of a brokered message in node js?

Tags: json, node.js, azure, json.net, azureservicebus

I am implementing socket.io server in node js (socketio.js) for my windows azure project. My worker role is in c#. And am sending a brokered message from worker role to socketio.js through service bus queue. But The object which am sending through the brokered message is not getting serialized into a json object. I dont know how to access the body of this brokered message in node js.

I can show how am sending the brokered message in the worker role and how am receiving it in the node js script.

The response body of brokered message(i.e message.body)

```
@rrayOfTestModelHhttp://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Project.Model     ☺i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance☺
```

TestModel is the name of the object model which am sending through the brokered message body.

Worker Role:

```
 BrokeredMessage socketioMessage = new BrokeredMessage(messageObject);
            WorkerRoleClient.Send(socketioMessage );
```

Node Js script:

```
serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(queue, function (error, receivedMessage) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(receivedMessage);
        if (receivedMessage != null) {
            var messageBody = receivedMessage.body;
            console.log(messageBody);       

            io.sockets.emit('news', messageBody);
}}
```

the message body i receive here is some plain unreadable string. And i am sending proper objects from the worker role. Please let me know if any of you have an idea about whats going wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a way to de serialize it and getting the json objects.

Worker Role in C#

```
var recordsMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
BrokeredMessage socketMessage = new BrokeredMessage(recordsMessage);
```

Receiving in Node js:

```
if (receivedMessage != null) {
            var messageBody = receivedMessage.body;

            var jsonString = messageBody.substring(messageBody.indexOf('['), messageBody.indexOf("]")+1);                

            var recordsQueue = JSON.parse(jsonString);
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old ticket but i guess it might help people in the future as it helped me today :).

Instead of using substring from your nodejs app, you have the possibility to directly send the message in string without the automatic serialization.

To do so, use the following code :

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write("Start");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage(stream) { ContentType = "text/plain" });
        }
```

Hope it will help,

Clément

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to find a reference to help doing this, please check the following link:  http://www.rackspace.com/blog/node-swiz-node-js-library-for-serializing-deserializing-and-validating-objects-in-rest-apis/

it shows the serialization and the deserialization using Node JS in any of the requested format (JSON or XML)

let me know if this work with you :)